# Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/linker'/Implementing threeJS in Angular environment

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I'm creating my threeJS/WebGL/Angular environment for the first time.
After creating my webpack.config.js and update the angular.json configuration with the new one, the application doesn't run.
The terminal displays this error.
I hope you can help me. Many thanks

`Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/linker'`

My webpack.config.js

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      // all files with a `.ts` or `.tsx` extension will be handled by `ts-loader`
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" },
      { test: /\.(glsl|vs|fs)$/, loader: "ts-shader-loader" }
    ]
  }
};
```

My angular.json

```
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./webpack.config.js"
            },
            ....
            "serve": {
            "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
            "options": {
            "browserTarget": "boilerpalate:build"
            },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall the Angular CLI and install the latest version.try this below code:-

```
npm uninstall angular-cli
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

Or

```
npm uninstall angular-cli
npm install @angular/cli --save-dev
```

Or execute this :- `npm i @angular/compiler-cli`

Hope it will resolve your issue.

Comment: Hi Pritom, I got the problem. The problem was the different version of @angular/core and @angular/compiler-cli.
Anyway, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the server first and still if it doesn't work then try to delete the node_modules folder and running

```sh
$ npm install
```

or

```sh
$ yarn add
```

Comment: Hi Darshan, thank you to answer me, but I already tried many time and I still have the same error

Comment: @Raquel This happens many times in big projects using js, that there are so many dependencies and one dependency might not work with some other dependency properly. So please check your dependencies properly

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following commands if not tried already:

```
rm -r node_modules //or delete your node_modules folder manually
npm cache clean --force
npm install
```